# Link to external mainpage

Tags: documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

I have made a Doxygen documentation, which itself references another documentation using the tag-file mechanism. But inside its mainpage I now would like to link to the mainpage of the external documentation. Of course, I can always specify the file directly:

```
... uses [OtherDoc](../../../OtherProject/doc/html/index.html) for ...
```

even more so since the projects are located relative to each other. But nevertheless I would like Doxygen to automate this process, since it needs to know the location of the external documentation, anyway.

So is there a way to somehow symbolically reference the external documentation's mainpage, something along the lines of:

```
[OtherDoc](\ref OtherProject::mainpage)
```

or

```
[OtherDoc](#OtherProject::mainpage)
```

Comment: If you close your open bounty I will add a higher one.

Comment: Very good question. We will probably have to wait till the end of the bounty period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick to do this. Say you have projects A and B, then in the main page of project A you could put an `@anchor` command like so:

```
/** @mainpage
 *  @anchor project_a
 */
```

And in the documentation of project b you can then simply use

```
 [OtherDoc](\ref project_a)
```

Note that anchors have to be globally unique, so you need to carefully choose them!

Comment: Since the answer comes directly from you, I can assume this is the best and most direct way to achieve this?

Comment: The problem is now only, that the link opens the page slightly scrolled down (making the mainpage's title disappear), because I have to place the anchor below the `{#mainpage}`-labeled heading, in order for the markdown file to be correctly recognized as mainpage. But I may be able to live with that, at least the goal is a step nearer now.

Comment: The best solution would be to have a way to explicitly tell doxygen where to look for a symbol, so you could use something like \ref a.tag:index to refer to project A's index page. That's currently not implemented though.

Comment: Has this still not been fixed?