# Doxygen: Link to tagged library's mainpage

Tags: doxygen

In a documentation page in one project, I need to put a link to an external library's Doxygen mainpage.

I found this: [Link to external mainpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700452/link-to-external-mainpage)

However, it is six years old and I'm *hoping* that the issue raised in the comments of the answer has been fixed by now, but can find no reference to this in any documentation or anywhere else on the internet.

The only thing I can think may work would be something like:

```
[link](@ref ExternalProjectName)
```

However: (1) external projects may have spaces in their name; and (2) is this even a reference name that can be used?

What reference name can I use for the mainpage of another project?

Comment: Did you try it with the current version of doxygen (1.8.14)?

Comment: Did I try what? There's no documentation on what tag to use to point to it.

Comment: You write " I need to put a link to an external library's Doxygen mainpage" so showing the MWE what you tried would be in place.

Comment: @Albert - Updated the question